# How to use Java Mission Control (or other solutions) with ColdFusion (tomcat)

Tags: coldfusion

The ColdFusion monitor is great for details about the server itself but it is pretty limited when it comes to the JVM.

How can one implement Java Mission Control or similar JVM monitoring solution to monitor the JVM running ColdFusion while you are developing and testing performance / memory footprint of applications and features?

*Note that I am asking this question for "community knowledge" and already know the answer, but feel free to contribute any tidbits about other monitoring solutions.*

Comment: Good Q/A but it's going to end up being closed because it belongs better on http://serverfault.com

Comment: I don't understand why. While SysAdmins might find this useful, this is strictly for development. Programmers need to be able to monitor their JVMs when developing features for high traffic sites. Being able to view young generation activity and get access to visual heapdumps to check footprint is important. .NET developers have this integrated in their IDE.

Comment: it has nothing to do with actual coding.

Comment: The guidelines state:a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. Doesn't this fall under software tools used by programmers?

Comment: I'm going to retract my close vote now you've amended your question to emphasise you're meaning its use for _'developing and testing'_ rather than just server administrators

Comment: Thanks, Duncan. I'm not even sure how you use it in production since it isn't licensed for production. I'm sure the instructions would be different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mission control used to be bundled as as it's own utility application in the JRockit JDK. Hotspot and JRockit were two entirely different JVMs with their own JDK/JREs. By default, ColdFusion uses the HotSpot JVM. JRockit is basically defunct from new development with some of its features being merged into HotSpot.

Java Mission Control is free for development purposes.

Get started, download the the latest 1.8 JDK. My preference is to uninstall all other 64-bit JDKs and JREs installed at this time.

1. This step might not be needed. Change your environment variable to update your JAVA home.

   a. Right click "My Computer" -> "Properties" -> "Advanced" -> "Environment Variables"

   b. Change JAVA_HOME and any other JAVA vars to your new path
2. Adjust your jvm.config

   a. Make a .bak copy of C:\ColdFusion1x\cfusion\bin\jvm.config

   b. Add the following lines to the jvm.config

   -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures

   -XX:+FlightRecorder

   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.autodiscovery=true

   -Dcom.sun.management.jdp.name=ColdFusion10

   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091

   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
3. Open C:\program files\java\jdk1.8_**\lib\missioncontrol\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info file with administrator privileges and remove the four lines that start with the following text:

   ```
   org.eclipse.equinox.log.nl_ja

   org.eclipse.equinox.log.nl_zh

   org.eclipse.equinox.supplement.nl_ja

   org.eclipse.equinox.supplement.nl_zh
   ```
4. Edit the C:\program files\java\jdk1.8_xx\lib\missioncontrol\configuration\config.ini, and add the following line: eclipse.home.location=$osgi.install.area$
5. Start up : C:\program files\java\jdk_1.8.0_**\bin\jmc
       Note that JMC is launching from 1.8 while your ColdFusion instance is running with whatever the latest Hotspot version you have installed with your ColdFusion updater.
6. You can install plugins from the help -> install new software. The plugins site should already be there. This will give you full on memory analysis of a heap dump. It's not nearly as good as the JRockit memory analyzer, but it's better than nothing.
7. If you are running ColdFusion as a Windows service, you will need to open services.msc and shutdown your ColdFusion Application Server. Then open C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\cfstart.bat to fire up Tomcat and ColdFusion as a foreground application. The jOverflow plugin will not work when running as a windows service.
8. You will see your JVM appear in Java Mission Control, mine is call -Xdebug since I guess it has no name and starts with the first option.
9. Right click on your ColdFusion JVM and select "Start JMX console". You will see something that looks like this show up on the right:

[image: Image capture of Java Mission Control]

10. There is a whole lot to explore, including a lot of junk when it comes to examining memory due to having to sift through the ColdFusion Framework itself, but there are a ton of tutorials for deciphering what it means.
        This video is your primary introduction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMEpRUgp9Y4

---

### References:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMEpRUgp9Y4

http://www.ghidinelli.com/2009/07/16/finding-memory-leaks-coldfusion-jvm

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jmc53-release-notes-2157171.html (see "known issues" section)

Comment: Do I understand correctly: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091` opens a port on my computer that will be accessible from other machines, too. It's possible from every other PC to log the memory usage on my PC. Is it possible to limit the access to the local machine? Despite using the windows firewall.

Comment: Good question -- I would say absolutely. I only use this in a firewalled non-production environment.

Comment: In the meantime I found this instruction that describes how to setup and use self signed certificates.I assume the JAVA application only accepts requests from Flight Recorders using the same certificate: https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/managing_java_flight_recorder_enabled